# Menu hyperlink in table not working in chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I need some help. I copied and pasted some code using my current understanding of CSS and HTML to come up with this menu button. When I click the links, they seem to work in Safari.

In Chrome or Firefox when I hover it recognizes the href attribute but whenI click, nothing happens.

I think it might have to do with the use of :focus in the CSS but that does not seem to solve the problem.

At this point I'm just scratching my head. Any help would be useful. I only know CSS and HTML, no JS.
Thanks!

This is a snippet of the code:

```css
partners_01 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 12px 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: 400;
  /*z-index:999999;*/
  cursor: pointer;
}

.partners_01:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.dropdown_01 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown_01-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /*z-index: 1;*/
}

.dropdown_01-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown_01-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown_01:focus .dropdown_01-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown_01:hover partners_01. {
  background-color: #7e8e31;
}


.dropdown_01:focus .partners_01 {background:#000; 
color:#fff;
border-radius: 2px;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown_01" tabindex="0">

  <a class="partners_01">View Partners</a>
  <div class="dropdown_01-content">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><strong><a href="http://clients.mndsign.com/smart/bang-olufsen/" target="_blank">Bang &amp; Olufsen</a></strong><a class="noclick_01">--</a><a href="http://architetturasonora.com/" target="_blank">Architectura Sonora</a><a href="http://www.artcoustic.com/"
            target="_blank">Artcoustic</a></td>
          <td style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="https://www.crestron.com/"><strong>Crestron</strong></a><a class="noclick_01">--</a><a href="https://www.graysound.nl/">Gray Loudspeakers</a><a href="http://www.jamesloudspeaker.com/">James Loudspeakers</a></td>
          <td style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="https://www.meridian-audio.com/" target="_blank"><strong>Meridian</strong></a><a class="noclick_01">--</a><a href="https://www.savant.com/" target="_blank">Savant</a><a href="https://www.screeninnovations.com/">Screen Innovations</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Starting a click (mousedown) on a link makes dropdown_01 loose focus, so the link is not visible any more, and so when the mouseup triggers it's not on the link, so you didn't click on your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the display and use the visibility css property.
Start with the .dropdown_01-content as hidden, then with the focus make it visible, then add a hover state of visible so that the links are clicked. I put a yellow background to make sure the hover state works on the hidden div.

```css
partners_01 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 12px 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.partners_01:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.dropdown_01 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown_01-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown_01-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown_01-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown_01:focus .dropdown_01-content {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown_01-content:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  background: yellow;
}

.dropdown_01:hover partners_01. {
  background-color: #7e8e31;
}

.dropdown_01:focus partners_01 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown_01" tabindex="0">

  <a class="partners_01">View Partners</a>
  <div class="dropdown_01-content">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><strong><a href="https://clients.mndsign.com/smart/bang-olufsen/">Bang &amp; Olufsen</a></strong><a class="noclick_01">--</a><a href="https://architetturasonora.com/">Architectura Sonora</a><a href="https://www.artcoustic.com/">Artcoustic</a></td>
          <td style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="https://www.crestron.com/"><strong>Crestron</strong></a><a class="noclick_01">--</a><a href="https://www.graysound.nl/">Gray Loudspeakers</a><a href="https://www.jamesloudspeaker.com/">James Loudspeakers</a></td>
          <td style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="https://www.meridian-audio.com/"><strong>Meridian</strong></a><a class="noclick_01">--</a><a href="https://www.savant.com/">Savant</a><a href="https://www.screeninnovations.com/">Screen Innovations</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```